# SSH Users Windows 10 Group

Tags: windows-10, ssh, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just noticed an user group I had never seen before in Windows 10 Pro x64 (1607) (look at the last group):

[image: SSH Users Group]

Why is this group present? I have never seen it before nor I created it.

I do have Windows Linux Subsystem installed. I am not aware it includes an SSH daemon.

What makes me weary of this is that a [search for the group's description on Google brings 0 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Members%20of%20this%20group%20can%20remotely%20access%20this%20computer%20over%20SSH%20protocol.%22).

Either something is fishy or I am just the first person to notice and comment about this on the internet (unlikely).

Comment: I am not willing to add the feature to my system, so I will have to spend time creating a virtual machine, but I would almost guarantee this user group is added when the Linux Subsystem is enabled with the intention that you need SSH into order to access the Linux subsystem remotely.  It also appears the SSH Server has been around awhile, [Windows 10 Insider: integrated SSH server](https://noise.paulos.cz/post/windows10-14352-ssh-server/), take notice of the warnings about the elevated status of the server itself though

Answer (score 0):

Recently I do a hard reaserch about this on google (maybe 2 or 3 hours) and after kicked some bad boys, I had get this info from the windows evil side: Yes OpenSSH Client and Server are now native avalible at the Insiders Preview when you activate the developers mode, by adding the optional featurs, that is, in the configuration menu search **"Manage Configuration Manage"**, then click in **"Add a feature"** and then, install **OpenSSH-Client (beta) and/or OpenSSH-Server (beta)**. Well if you'r not familiarized with SSH, it's a remote manage option in non-graphic mode, very popular on Linux based systems, the group it's to manage the allowed acounts to get conection in your pc.

Well, if you want to try by yourself, I bring you some links:
  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/12/15/using-the-openssh-beta-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-and-windows-server-1709/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqz6auCMqkI

Hope this answer the question, and put the links to many

Answer (score -1):

If you scroll to the bottom of this page, you'll find, that SSH server didn't yet hit production:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2015/10/19/openssh-for-windows-update/

You could check if the group has any members. If it has members, you don't recognize, you should definitely remove them.

Comment: The blog article you linked to is a year out of date.  I based that statement on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4w4sew/windows_10_has_a_native_ssh_server/) information

Comment: He refers to the comments by the MS peeps at the bottom, @Ramhound
I had seen that article but it says nothing about it being rolled out, and I am not on the inside preview channel nor in the fast or slow ring.

Comment: @Gaia - It has been rolled out.  The article is over a year old. The article does not apply to Version 1607, or I can find no evidence, that it applies.